# "list indices must be integers or slices, not str" while manipulating data from JSON

Tags: python, json, typeerror

I am trying to extract some data from JSON files, which are have all the same structure and then write the chosen data into a new JSON file. My goal is to create a new JSON file which is more or less a list of each JSON file in my folder with the data:
Filename, triggerdata, velocity {imgVel, trigVel}, coordinates.

In a further step of my programme, I will need this new splitTest1 for analysing the data of the different files.

I have the following code:

```
base_dir = 'mypath'
def createJsonFile() :
    splitTest1 = {}
    splitTest1['20mm PSL'] = []
    for file in os.listdir(base_dir):
        # If file is a json, construct it's full path and open it, append all json data to list
        if 'json' in file:
            json_path = os.path.join(base_dir, file)
            json_data = pd.read_json(json_path, lines=True)
            if splitTest1[file]['20mm PSL'] == to_find:
                splitTest1['20mm PSL'].append({
                    'filename': os.path.basename(base_dir),
                    'triggerdata': ['rawData']['adcDump']['0B'],
                    'velocity': {
                        'imgVel': ['computedData']['particleProperties']['imgVelocity'],
                        'trigVel': ['computedData']['img0Properties']['coordinates']},
                    'coordinates': ['computedData']['img1Properties']['coordinates']})
    print(len(splitTest1))
```

When I run the code, I get this error:

```
 'triggerdata': ['rawData']['adcDump']['0B'], TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

What is wrong with the code? How do I fix this?

This is my previous code how I accessed that data without saving it in another JSON File:

```
with open('myJsonFile.json') as f0:
    d0 = json.load(f0)
y00B = d0['rawData']['adcDump']['0B']

x = np.arange(0, (2048 * 0.004), 0.004)  # in ms, 2048 Samples, 4us

def getData():
    return y00B, x

def getVel():
    imgV = d0['computedData']['particleProperties']['imgVelocity']
    trigV = d0['computedData']['trigger']['trigVelocity']
    return imgV, trigV
```

Basically, I am trying to put this last code snippet into a loop which is reading all my JSON files in my folder and make a new JSON file with a list of the names of these files and some other chosen data (like the ['rawData']['adcDump']['0B'], etc)

Comment: What do you expect `['rawData']['adcDump']['0B']` to mean? Should that be a list that has three strings in it? Or something else?

Comment: I edited the question to attempt to ask your question more clearly and to remove noise.

Comment: before, i accessed the data of this line like this:  ```with open('PSL/2020-06-29_15h/poleno-2_2020-06-29_15.01.01.870424_event.json') as f0:
    d0 = json.load(f0)
y00B = d0['rawData']['adcDump']['0B']``` so i am basically trying to do this but in a for loop and save this data in a new JSON file. The y00B is a list with 2048 items (int)

Comment: now i am trying to get more information than only the ['rawData']['adcDump']['0B'. I used the brackets in this loop because this is how I used to get the information(see my comment before). But because I needed to access every file singularly I tried making a for loop for a better workflow and a cleaner - not spaghetti - code

Comment: So, when you write `d0['computedData']['particleProperties']['imgVelocity']`, `d0` is the thing you index into with `'computedData'`, then that result gets indexed into `'particleProperties'`, then that thing with `'imgVelocity'`. Right? So, what do you expect to happen when you just have `['computedData']['particleProperties']['imgVelocity']`? What do you *want* it to be indexing into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume what you want to do is to take some data from several json files and compile those into a list and write that into a new json file.

In order to get the data from your current json file you'll need to add a "reference" to it in front of the indices (otherwise the code has no idea where it should that data from). Like so:

```
base_dir = 'mypath'
def createJsonFile() :
    splitTest1 = {}
    splitTest1['20mm PSL'] = []
    for file in os.listdir(base_dir):
        # If file is a json, construct it's full path and open it, append all json data to list
        if 'json' in file:
            json_path = os.path.join(base_dir, file)
            json_data = pd.read_json(json_path, lines=True)
            if splitTest1[file]['20mm PSL'] == to_find:
                splitTest1['20mm PSL'].append({
                    'filename': os.path.basename(base_dir),
                    'triggerdata': json_data['rawData']['adcDump']['0B'],
                    'velocity': {
                        'imgVel': json_data['computedData']['particleProperties']['imgVelocity'],
                        'trigVel': json_data['computedData']['img0Properties']['coordinates']},
                    'coordinates': json_data['computedData']['img1Properties']['coordinates']})
    print(len(splitTest1))
```

So basically what you need to do is to add "json_data" in front of the indices.

Also I suggest you to write the variable "json_path" and not "base_dir" into the 'filename' field.

Comment: Thank you! I tried it with the reference but also needed to change how I am reading my JSON files. I Posted the full answer in a new Post

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution with help of the post from Mattu475

I had to add the reference in front of the indices and also change on how to open the files found in my folder with the following code;

```
with open (json_path) as f0:
   json_data = json.load(f0)
```

instead of pd.read_json(...)

Here the full code:

```
def createJsonFile() :
    splitTest1 = {}
    splitTest1['20mm PSL'] = []
    for file in os.listdir(base_dir):
        # If file is a json, construct it's full path and open it, append all json data to list
        if 'json' in file:
            print("filename: " ,file) # file is only the file name, the path not included
            json_path = os.path.join(base_dir, file)
            print("path : ", json_path)
            with open (json_path) as f0:
                json_data = json.load(f0)
            splitTest1['20mm PSL'].append({
                'filename': os.path.basename(json_path),
                'triggerdata': json_data['rawData']['adcDump']['0B'],
                #'imgVel': json_data['computedData']['particleProperties']['imgVelocity'],
                'trigVel': json_data['computedData']['trigger']['trigVelocity'],
                #'coordinatesImg0': json_data['computedData']['img0Properties']['coordinates'],
                #'coordinatesImg1': json_data['computedData']['img1Properties']['coordinates']
            })
    return splitTest1
```

few lines (the ones commented out) do not function 100% yet, but the rest works.

Answer (score 0):

Your dict value isn't legal Python.

```
'triggerdata': ['rawData']['adcDump']['0B']
```

The value doesn't make any sense: you make a list of a single string, then you try to index it with another string.  You asked for element "adcDump" of the list `['rawData']`, and there isn't any such syntax.

You cannot store arbitrary source code (your partial expression) as if it were a data value.

Comment: I edited my question, below the original question you can see now the code of how I accessed the information in the JSON files before without saving it into a new one. Hope this helps you better understand my problem

Comment: You still have the basic problem: you seem to be trying to access the data structure by subscripts alone, without explicitly naming the structure.  This is not legal.  You have to include the structure with the subscripts.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with this line

`'imgVel': ['computedData']['particleProperties']['imgVelocity'],`

And the two that come after that. What's happening there is you're creating a list with the string 'computedData' as the only element. And then trying to find the index 'particleProperties', which doesn't make sense. You can only index a list with integers. I can't really give you a "solution", but if you want `imgVel` to just be a list of those strings, then you would do

`'imgVel': ['computedData', 'particularProperties', 'imgVelocity']`

Comment: I edited my question, below the original question you can see now the code of how I accessed the information in the JSON files before without saving it into a new one. Hope this helps you better understand my problem